# $n$ points in the plane can be connected with $n-1$ clockwise, non-intersecting line segments from any starting point

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics, combinatorial-geometry

This conjecture is based on a [mobile game](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/clockwise/id6444231349) that I've published. The object of the game is:

- Given $n ≥ 3$ points in the Cartesian plane in general position (no $3$ of those points are a straight line):
- Connect all the points with $n - 1$ line segments, drawn continuously (without lifting pencil from paper). Drawing lines in this way forms a **permutation** of the set of $n$ points, with each line segment being defined by the $n-1$ subsequences of $2$ consecutive points in that permutation. (No line segment is drawn between the first and last points in the permutation.)
- Every subsequence of $3$ consecutively connected points must be clockwise [oriented](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorOrientation.html) in the order that they were connected.
- No two of the line segments may intersect.

Equations that precisely define clockwise orientation and line intersection are provided under the "Insights" section of this post.

I've already proven that every instance of this game is solvable *if* the player gets to choose the point at which they start: Start at a point on the convex hull of the set of points, then continue making connections in a clockwise spiral to minimize each successive angle between line segments until every point has been reached.

Example solution:
[image]

However, I conjecture that the game is also solvable by using any **arbitrary** point as the starting point, even if it's not on the convex hull of all the points.

I have not yet manually created a counterexample to this conjecture, and I've also searched millions of possible levels using a computer program without finding a counterexample. However, I have yet to formally prove the conjecture.

**Clarification:**

Here's another wording of the problem:

Given a set of $n ≥ 3$ points $\{P_1, P_2, ..., P_n\}$ in general position, and given an arbitrary point $Q$ from that set, does there always exist a permutation of that set satisfying the following conditions:

- The first element of the permutation is $Q$
- None of the following line segments intersect with each other: $\overline{P_i P_{i+1}}$ for each $i \in [1, n-1]$
- Referring to $P_i$, $P_{i+1}$, and $P_{i+2}$ as $(A_x, A_y)$, $(B_x, B_y)$, and $(C_x, C_y)$ for each $i \in [1, n-2]$, the following condition is always satisfied: $\begin{vmatrix}(B_x - A_x)&(B_y - A_y)\\(C_x - A_x)&(C_y - A_y)\end{vmatrix}<0$

**Alternative strategy:**

If an alternative conjecture can be proven where $Q$ is the *last* element of the permutation instead of the first element, then the original conjecture also holds.

Reasoning: If the original conjecture holds for a set of points $S$, then the alternative conjecture holds for $S'$, where $S'$ has the points from $S$ reflected across a given arbitrary line (such as the y-axis).

**Insights:**

Whether two line segments intersect depends upon whether trios of their points are clockwise-oriented. This correspondence may be usable to generalize the problem, though I am not yet sure how.

Let $c(A, B, C)$ be true iff A, B, and C are clockwise-oriented and false otherwise. Let $i(A, B, C, D)$ be true iff $\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{CD}$ intersect with each other and false otherwise. Then:

$c(A, B, C) = (\begin{vmatrix}(B_x - A_x)&(B_y - A_y)\\(C_x - A_x)&(C_y - A_y)\end{vmatrix}<0)$

$i(A, B, C, D) = (c(A, B, C) \oplus c(A, B, D)) \land (c(C, D, A) \oplus c(C, D, B))$

The following identities hold on the function $c$:

$c(A, B, C) = c(B, C, A) = c(C, A, B)$

$c(A, B, C) \oplus c(C, B, A)$ always evaluates to true

The function $f(N)$ that gives the number of sets of N points that are *distinct* (defined below) is given by [A000930](https://oeis.org/A000930), where $f(N)$ is the Nth element of that sequence. (Obviously, $f(1)$ and $f(2)$ are meaningless in the context of this problem.) For example, there is only one distinct set of $3$ points — they form a triangle. For $4$ points, there are $2$ distinct sets — one with a convex hull of 4 points and one with a single point within a convex hull of 3 other points.

Distinctness for the purpose of this result is defined by:

- the number of times the convex hull of the set of points can be removed before no points remain (i.e. the number of nested convex hulls in the initial set of points), and
- the numbers of points on each of the nested convex hulls.

I believe, but have not yet formally proven, that the solution for any set of points $S$ is generalizable to any other set of points $T$ if $S$ and $T$ are not distinct by the above definition.

**Insights from answers:**

- Carlyle proved that for a set of points $S$, a solution can always be found if the initial point is in $T$ or $U$, where $T$ is the convex hull of $S$, and $U$ is the convex hull of $(S - T)$.

  - It follows that a solution can be found for any initial point in a set of $6$ or fewer points.

**Insights from comments:**

Thank you so much to everyone who's left comments! Here is a summary of the ideas and insights derived from my and others' comments.

- There have been misconceptions about the meaning of "clockwise". This term is precisely defined in the "clarification" and "insights" sections of my question.
- Observe the manner in which the following set of points is connected according to the rules in the problem statement: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOMgp.png.
- The above set of points does *not* generalize to all sets of points with 3 convex hulls within each other (e.g. 3 convex hulls inscribed within concentric circles). Why does this not generalize? Consider the case of 4 convex hulls inscribed within concentric circles. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcNCS.png) is the general solution (with an arbitrarily large number of points on each). [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sGIQ.png) is a specific case, with a *different* solution than the general case.

**Mobile game screenshots:**

These screenshots illustrate the conjecture in the context of the mobile game ("Clockwise!" by me, Roy Sianez, available on the iOS App Store within the US). I'm attaching them as an image because the App Store link may not show the product page outside of the US.

[image]

Comment: For your game, does the line joining $(2,0)$ to $(3,0)$ intersect the line joining $(3,0)$ to $(1,0)$ ?

Comment: @AdamRubinson those three points are colinear, so not in general position.

Comment: The proof should be quite simple - place another point in the middle of the set of points. Now connect this point to all other points. You could now systematically select the segments in order to go through all points around. This also demonstrates that you could start with any point. How the game plays is a separate issue:)

Comment: @Moti that gives you $n$ segments, not $n-1$.  Moreover, from the phrasing of the question ("first" and "last" points) I think OP intends that the points are connected with the $k$-th segment joining points $k$ and $k+1$.

Comment: As I read it the intent is to connect points in a certain way. Actually, the above proves that there are many ways to create convex polygons with n, to male it n-1 is straightforward.

Comment: What is the game called? The link doesn’t work for me.

Comment: My apologies, the link to the game may only work within the United States. The game is called "Clockwise!" and is available on the iOS App Store within the US. I'll update my post with a screenshot of the App Store product page for illustration.

Comment: @MW Looking at videos of the game on the app store, there's no distinction I can see between the points on the plane that need to be connected; it looks like they're allowed to be connected in arbitrary order with any start and any end point.

Comment: @Moti nitpickery: the polygon you build is _star shaped_ but not necessarily convex. (Indeed, if e.g. one point falls inside the convex hull of some other three then you can't build a convex polygon through all the points).

Comment: @StevenStadnicki right, but they must be connected in a sequence, was my point.  You cannot connect point $A$ to point $B$, then point $A$ to $C$, then $A$ to $D$, as I interpreted Moti's comment to imply.

Comment: @MW Ahhh; I think you misinterpreted their comment, then. The idea is that you sort the points by angle from some point that's in general position with them (since they're in general position, you don't have to worry about the center you choose lining up with any two other points) and then chain them together in the order of those angles: A to B to C to etc. Since each link of that chain covers a different 'span' of angles from the center you chose, there's no way for them to intersect.

Comment: You might think of it as standing at some arbitrary position, aiming in an arbitrary direction; then start turning clockwise until your target hits one of the points. That'll be your starting point. Keep turning clockwise until the target hits another one; that'll be the point you link your starting point to. Etc, etc. Since you never go backwards, there's no way for any of these links to cross each other.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki maybe I’m just being slow, but it’s not clear to me how that makes the desired angles clockwise.  In fact, the path created the way you describe might jump inward and jump out again, so even if the angle formed with the “origin” (the point you’re standing at) is increasing clockwise, the angle formed by the path is not clockwise.

Comment: @MW No, you're not being slow; that's legitimately just something I (and possibly Moti) just completely missed in the description of the problem. Mea culpa!

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Every subsequence of 3 consecutive points in the sequence of all the connected points must be clockwise by the definition in the post — as you mentioned, this would exclude the "star-shaped" polygons that you and Moti described unless they were also convex.

Comment: Additionally, you are right that the points must be connected in a sequence — connecting the points with line segments just forms a permutation of the set of points. The sequence of connected points must contain each point exactly once, and the line segments come from every subsequence of 2 consecutive points.

Comment: Connecting the points "in order of those angles" between each point and an additional point not in the set yields a sequence for which the non-intersection property holds, but _not_ necessarily the clockwise property.

Comment: Can we connect clockwise [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeuRO.png) set starting from the red point?

Comment: @AlexRavsky seems fine to me. Do the middle circle (clockwise) first, then do the outer circle, then the inner circle.

Comment: @BenjaminWang I expect when we go from the middle circle to the inner circle, we have to intersect out path along the middle circle.

Comment: @AlexRavsky Ah I see. I forgot about that requirement. Are your points defined equidistantly or manually placed? Perhaps OP can use their algorithm to search for a solution.

Comment: @BenjaminWang The issue of the point placement is that they should be placed sufficiently dense along the circles.

Comment: @AlexRavsky Yes, your set of points can be connected like so: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOMgp.png

Comment: Good. Let us expand Stonehengde. :-) What is we add one more circle of points between the outer circle and the middle one? The reason is that this construction is generic. Namely, each finite plane set $S$ can be similarly decomposed: let $S_1$ be the set of the vertices of the convex hull of $S$, $S_2$ be the set of the vertices of the convex hull of $S\setminus S_1$,  and so forth. So if we can connect the points in the circular examples then maybe we can similarly connect the points in any finite plane set $S$, using its above decomposition.

Comment: @AlexRavsky The circles of points generalize well to cases where each convex hull has a suitably large number of points along the hull's polygon. However, if I remember correctly, there are cases that can be solved one way with a sufficient number of points along each convex hull, but that must be solved another way when there are fewer points along the _same_ convex hulls. This may mean that the construction of concentric circles is (unfortunately) not generic to all problems in the domain. I will try to post an example to illustrate this later tonight.

Comment: [Following up on my last comment] Here is a general solution for a sufficiently large number of points around 4 concentric circles, starting from the second-to-innermost: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcNCS.png. Here is an instance of 16 points that have 4 square convex hulls inscribed within the same concentric circles: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sGIQ.png. The specific case has a _different_ solution from the general case, which illustrates the limitations of generalizing with concentric circles.

Comment: @RoySianez it is worth summarising comment-observations in your question because comments are not as visible.

Comment: I believe I have an algorithm that works in general, but I have not been able to prove its correctness: take the starting point and find the nested hull that it lies on, draw a line that passes through the two line segments adjacent to the starting point (connecting it to the other points on its hull) now take the orientation of this line and start at one side of the set of points, and start sweeping it across, whenever the line sweeps past a point, neglect that point and calculate the new hulls with the remaining points. I believe that this procedure will always have a step where

Comment: ...this procedure will always have a step where the starting point is isolated inside the most central hull, at this step, take a point just above the line, on the outermost hull and spiral inwards, anti-clockwise. This spiral is guaranteed to end on the starting point. Then take all those points below the line, and start on the rightmost one on the outermost hull just below the line, and spiral clockwise, then simply connect the two starting points of the spiral, and you have a solution. The struggle is proving that at some step the starting point is isolated in the innermost hull

Comment: @Carlyle, could you please attach an illustration to clarify your algorithm? I am specifically confused by "take the orientation of this line and… start sweeping it across", and by the way in which the construction yields a set of convex hulls whose center is the starting point. If you indeed have a valid construction for which this property always holds, such a construction could potentially prove the conjecture.

Comment: @MW Thank you — I have edited my question to reflect what I meant, which is that $U$ is the _convex hull of_ $(S-T)$.

Comment: Let $P$ be the starting point. As @Carlyle says, it suffices to prove that $S$ can be split by a line into two sets $A$ and $B$ such that $\{P\}$ is the centermost nested hull of $A$. That way, an anti clockwise path in $A$ can be drawn from an outer point of $A$, say $Q_A$, that connects clockwise**¹** with the outer hull of $B$. This path will end at $P$. Now reverse this path, go to the outer hull of $B$, and concatenate it with a clockwise path in $B$. **¹**I mean that $Q_A$ must allow for a clockwise switch from $A$ to $B$.

Comment: If $P$ is on the outer hull, take $A=\{P\}$. I didn't say we can *expect* such division to be possible (though I do, based on the examples I've looked at) but that *if* it's possible, then the problem is solved. This division might be an interesting rephrasing of the problem because it uses more "natural" terms (nested hulls, splitting) than the original form (non-intersecting clockwise permutations??). I mean, the nested hulls appear naturally in this problem, as first noticed Roy Sianez, so we might as well formulate it in terms of them.

Comment: @LucaT.Castrillón if this is in response to my comment, I made it too hastily, hence why I deleted.  I agree this seems like it solves the problem if it can be done., and is a good reformulation  Also, pretty sure that whenever there is a solution to original problem, you can always express it in the form very similar (if not identical) to what you described - solution will always spiral out from one point, until hitting and traversing outer hull, then spiral in to another point, and you can always (I believe) separate the spirals with a line.  so this seems close to an equivalent formulation.

Comment: Certainly, I think we can say at the minimum that when there is a solution, there is such a decomposition where $P$ is a member (maybe not a priori unique?) of the inner most hull of $A$.

Comment: @RoySianez I have added some diagrams to illustrate this algoritm, it seems LucaT.Castrillon agrees that it works, but also seems to think, as I do, that it is not easy to prove this splitting algorithm correct

Comment: @MW I agree that such a decomposition must exist, but I don't think it is sufficient to find a decomposition where $P$ is on the innermost hull, I believe it needs to be an isolated point as well, since there are some configurations where it is not possible to simply "spiral out" from any point on the inner-most hull, ironically, I think it is relatively easy to show that there is a decomposition landing $P$ on the innermost hull through induction

Answer (score 7):

Slight improvement: It is always possible to start on the second nested convex hull as well.

Firstly, by second nested convex hull, I mean the convex hull of the points obtained by removing all the points in the convex hull of the original set. (All the trivial cases such as a set with only one point not on the convex hull can be dealt with separately)

It is fairly straightforward to see why this is the case. Given a set of points $S$ and a point $x$ on the second nested convex hull of $S$, we can draw a line through $x$ that bisects $S$ into a region containing only points from the convex hull, and another region containing the rest of $S$. Below is an illustration of such a line drawn through such a point (please help me center this image):

[image]

The starting point is circled, and the line drawn is a line that bisects the plane into a region containing only points from the original convex hull, and the rest.

From here on, you can simply go to the most anti-clockwise point on the convex hull above the bisection line, call it $y$:

[image]

and complete the spiral as if you were completing it for the set of points $S\setminus\{x\}$ starting on the point $y$ which is on its convex hull, and this completion is guaranteed to not intersect the segment connecting $x$ to $y$, since none of the non-convex hull points of $S$ are above the bisection line, while the line segment connecting $x$ and $y$ is above the bisection line.

In general, if one starts on a non-convex hull point, then any path through the points satisfying the conditions of the problem will necessarily contain all but one line segment on the convex hull. This partial result came from trying to think how one might cleverly *choose* which line segment to omit, so that one of the spirals going in from one of the points adjacent to the omitted segment starts on the required point, since the path can then be completed in a way analogous to what is described above (I am leaving out some details mostly because I am still struggling to formalise this) but perhaps one can do a sort of induction on the number of nested convex hulls, to show that you can always cleverly choose an edge to omit, but my attempts at this have failed

**Edit, description of an algorithm I believe works, but have not been able to verify:

Take the starting point and find the nested hull that it lies on, draw a line that passes through the two line segments adjacent to the starting point (connecting it to the other points on its hull) now take the orientation of this line and start at one side of the set of points, and start sweeping it across, whenever the line sweeps past a point, neglect that point and calculate the new hulls with the remaining points. I believe that this procedure will always have a step where the starting point is isolated inside the most central hull, at this step, take a point just above the line, on the outermost hull and spiral inwards, anti-clockwise. This spiral is guaranteed to end on the starting point. Then take all those points below the line, and start on the rightmost one on the outermost hull just below the line, and spiral clockwise, then simply connect the two starting points of the spiral, and you have a solution. The struggle is proving that at some step the starting point is isolated in the innermost hull. Here are some diagrams showing the algorithm in action, hopefully someone can make it rigorous:

First, draw the nested convex hulls,and find a line going through the line segments adjacent to the starting point (the starting point is circled):

[image]

Now, shift this line all the way down (away from the point) and start sweeping it across:

[image]

Each time it passes a point, neglect that points, and draw the nested hulls for the points that remain, the "centers" of the nested hulls start collapsing towards the starting point, and eventually surpass it, but we are interested in finding the step at which the starting point appears isolated in the central hull:

[image]

At this point, take the rightmost point above the line, and spiral in anti-clockwise from that point (circled in red), also, complete the spiral below the line, starting with the rightmost point below the line:

[image]

Now connect the spirals, to obtain a full solution:

[image]

Comment: This seems like sound reasoning to me. The strategy indicated by your last paragraph — dividing the plane by separating 2 points from the convex hull, then solving the remainder of the puzzle by starting from the convex hull of the remaining points — will always work when starting on the "second nested convex hull" as described in your answer, but likely won't generalize to a third, fourth, etc. nested convex hull.

Comment: Nice idea for the 2nd nested hull. Can you please provide an illustration for why you believe the algorithm is true? I find it difficult to follow.

Comment: @BenjaminWang I have added in some diagrams, I hope it is clear now? It is not supposed to be a proof, just a tried and tested idea

Comment: I notice in your picture the starting point is already a member of the inner most hull.  Does this still generally seem to work if you put the starting point in one of the middle hulls?

Comment: @MW it does seem so yes, since if it is on a middle hull, sweeping far enough pushes it to a smaller and smaller hull (you can define a sort of positive and negative hull number, and sweeping past a single point changes the hull number of the point by at most one as far as I can tell, and you can sweep far enough to get the point to have a negative hull number, so it seems it should be able to get it on the innermost hull, but I haven't been able to formalise it all)

Comment: I see, so it's key that we start sweeping on the other side of the line that the point is on.  I think I was missing that part.

Comment: It's maybe useful to know that any two disjoint convex polygons can be separated by a line.

Comment: A maybe more relevant result is that a non intersecting path (not necessarily clockwise) starting at an arbitrary point and connecting all the others must exist: take the one that minimizes total length. It's easy to show that it can't intersect.

Comment: @LucaT.Castrillón you can also use the idea of one of the deleted answers to just get a non-self-intersecting path - pick any point not colinear with the ones in $S$, as a sort of center point, then rotate a ray around that center point, and connect the points in $S$ in the order that the ray hits them.

Comment: There is some further constraint for the sweeping line apart from just passing through the adjacent segments. Compare this [valid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhNx8.gif) sweep to this [invalid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26qXf.gif) sweep. In fact for this example any line parallel to one in the [green cone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKdXY.png) would work.

Comment: In fact, it is [not necessary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BMGz.gif) to intersect both the adjacent segments. Although in all the random examples I tried there is also a solution where the line does intersect both of the adjacent segments.

Comment: Nice @EeroHakavuori. Would you mind sharing your code?

Comment: @LucaT.Castrillón Sure, it's created using Sage. You can play with it here: [https://tinyurl.com/23wbc4kf](https://tinyurl.com/23wbc4kf). Link shortener because the permalink to sagecell.sagemath.org was too long to put in a comment.

Comment: @EeroHakavuori I noticed something in the linked SageMathCell. If one constructs a line on the starting point by bisecting the angle on its associated convex hull within the nested convex hull construction, then draws any line *perpendicular* to that line, the perpendicular line appears to not only be a valid sweeping line, but also "bisect" the sector of valid splittings. Does this observation square with your data?

Comment: I apologize, disregard my observation, I was working with a sample size that was too small.

Answer (score 3):

(this is supposed to be a comment, but I couldn't figure out how to add pictures in the comment sections).

@Carlyle's idea is very nice. I just want to point out one thing: the choice of the sweeping line cannot be arbitrary.

Consider this example of $6$ points.
[image: A configuration of 6 points]
Suppose we want to start from $D$. Then one cannot choose the sweeping line to be close to parallel to $EF$, as then $B$ will be removed first, and $D$ would lie on the convex hull. Instead, one must carefully choose the line so that $C$ and $F$ is removed.

Comment: I think here one cannot even choose anything close to parallel to $EF$.

Comment: Firstly, I cannot take credit for the idea, it was actually a friend of mine that came up with it, but he's not on stack exchange. Secondly, thank you for this example, it gives a lot of insight, because this means we will not be able to prove it using only the information given in my description, since the orientation of the line is too arbitrary